# Connect Android to Linux laptop

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, android

I would like to establish a network connection between a Linux laptop and an Android device. 
More specifically, there is an MPD server on the laptop which I wish to contact from the Android device using a client application.

I tried creating an Ad-hoc Wifi network on Linux but the Android cannot find the Wifi network. How can I proceed? Should I buy a Wifi access point or something like that? I do have a Wifi router, could it help me somehow?

Comment: I guess you could be more specific, about your linux box and android. Post a linux distribution, tools and steps you make to set up wifi ad-hoc network, which wifi card you have.

Comment: I have an Ubuntu 12.1. It's on a HP NC6400 laptop..I simply do "create a new Wireless network". The Android is a 4.1 version. I tryed to connect a Windows laptop with a fixed IP and the Linux machine to a TP-Link TL-WR740 and then tryed to ping from the Windows laptop to the linux machine it seems that the computer is not found.

Comment: Your TP-Link could be set to isolate wlan clients or your firewall rules on Ubuntu not allow ping. Is your android phone see another wifi network?

Comment: Not all Android devices support ad hoc networks. Is there any reason you can't use one of the several Android [MPD](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=mpd) clients? Also, so folks over at [android.se] look like they were trying to do something similar. [1](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8885/android-tablet-as-music-remote) [2](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4853/client-server-android-audio-remote) [3](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6072/is-it-possible-to-have-a-tcp-ip-network-using-bluetooth)

Answer (score 0):

*As regards to the Ad-Hoc network*:

on the android device try to manually define a new wifi network ("add wifi network") and use the same network name (ssid) you choose for your ad-hoc netwok on linux, and see if you can connect.

Then you have to check wich specific IP you have on the netbook and on the android device within the ad-hoc network (If the IPs are on the same sub-net its OK).

*As regards to the Router solution*:

(That solution will be more simple and straightforward to be able to share your MPD server)
If both devices are connected to the router then by default you can access from one device to another with the **automatically-router-assigned** IP (dhcp) the routher will gave to them. Do not try to fix the IP on the notebook, as you can be seeting an IP addres that is not within the routers IP sub-net (if you manually set, be careful).

Most probably, I believe, the ping does not work because the devices do not have IPs on the same subnetwork.

So I think the problem could be the manually-set IP. 
For the Ad-hoc netwok check both IPs (laptop and device) and make sure they are on the the same IP netwowk (net-mask) for all this to work.

In a router solution (if you have one, use it!) do not set IP manually (the routher will handle) or, if set, use the same IP subnetwork of the routher for both manually-set IPs on the devices (be careful with IPs).